# How to map user/password to a mobile theme?

Tags: users, theming

I'm working on a mobile version of a forgot password page, the problem I have is the mobile theme is triggered when users are on a page with a URL like:

`example.com/m/about`

Here, `about` would be a node and it's a mobile version of the `example.com/about`.

So I read through drupal documentation and looked at [Customizing and Overriding User Login page...](https://drupal.org/node/350634)but the issue I have is, how do I go about mapping `example.com/user/password` to a mobile version since it's not a node it's a template (`node--user.tpl.php`)?

Comment: Are you trying to re-theme the page or the form on the page?  The link you mentioned talks all about redoing the form, so if you do that in your theme, you are all set.  If, however, you are talking about the page itself, then you would look at `page--user--password.tpl.php` would override the template used to create the `www.example.com/user/password` page layout.

Comment: (And then, depending on how you are creating the `m` paths, `page--m--user--password.tpl.php` may also override the similar mobile page as well if creating an "m-less" template doesn't work in the theme itself)

Comment: So I want to keep the `/user/password` page in zen and I have another page which will use the same form but with a different UI `/m/user/password` which will be in zen mobile. I'm not sure how to redirect/map the mobile page only for mobile pages because when I create a node and alias it to `/m/user/password` drupal display no form.

Comment: Well the "I forgot my password" page isn't a node, it's a menu item in defined by the user module.  If you create a node and then alias it to `m/user/password` I really have no idea what would happen :)

Comment: But, if in your Zen theme, you create a `page--user--password.tpl.php` template, it will be used for when Zen displays the `www.example.com/user/password` page.  If you create a similar one in your mobile (or any other theme) then it will be used for that path when that theme is active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get around your problem (I say should because I haven't actually tried this):

Make a custom module that creates a menu item for the required url and makes it call the user password form.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function MODULENAME_menu() {
  $items = array();

  // A replica of the password reset page for mobile.
  // Based on the original menu item in user_menu().
  $items['m/user/password'] = array(
    'title' => 'Request new password',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('user_pass'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'file' => 'user.pages.inc',
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'user'),
  );

  return $items;
}
```

I foresee you having to do this for some other pages too.

Personally I would probably not make a mobile site in this fashion, I would use the same pages for mobile and non-mobile and then make them look different based on screen size.